# Mocking variable and replacing it with object

Tags: python, flask, testing, mocking, python-unittest

I'd like to test this piece of code:

```
modify: UserModifyPort = _ports_.user_modify_port


@_app_.route(f"/user", methods=["POST"])
@headers_check({"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"})
def create_user():
    body_json = request.get_json()
    body = UserCreateRequest(body_json["username"], body_json["password"])
    cmd = UserCreateCmd(body.username, body.password)
        
    # modify usage
    user_id = modify.create_user(cmd)
        
    response = UserCreateResponse(user_id)
    return response.to_dict(), 201
```

In this test I need to mock a global variable `modify` and replace it with object. I've been trying to do this like that:

```
# TEST
@mock.patch("application.user.user_rest_adapter.modify")
def test_create_user_should_create(modify_mock, db_engine, client, user_config):
    modify_mock.return_value = DatabaseUserModifyAdapter(db_engine, user_config)
    response = client.post("/user", headers={"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                           json={"username": "GALJO", "password": "qwerty123"})
```

But it isn't executing `modify.create_user()` function, it just returns some weird object:

```
<MagicMock name='modify.create_user()' id='140375141136512'>
```

How can I make this function work?

Comment: Is this pytest or unittest?

Comment: I'm using pytest, but unittest.mock for mocking

Comment: You mock *values*; you *patch* names (i.e., variables). I don't see any need to use a mock here. Just patch the name with a different value so that the original value is restored after the test.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue with sort of workaround. Instead of mocking entire object I've mocked just function that I use. There is no need to use another function, because it is tested in other tests so I replaced it with constant value. I've only checked if given args are correct, everything else is other test task.

```
@mock.patch("application.user.user_rest_adapter.modify.create_user")
def test_create_user_should_create(create_user_mock, client):
    # given
    user_id = "a20d7a48-7235-489b-8552-5a081d069078"
    create_user_mock.return_value = UUID(user_id)

    # when
    response = client.post("/user", headers={"Accept": "application/json", "Content-Type": "application/json"},
                           json={"username": "GALJO", "password": "qwerty123"})

    # then
    args = create_user_mock.call_args.args
    assert args[0].username == "GALJO"
    assert args[0].password == "qwerty123"
    assert response.json["userID"] == user_id
```